# How to identify a keymap conflict?

Tags: customization, add-on

I can't access the Clipping Border command (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) with my standard Blender setup. When I load factory settings everything works okay, so I presume there must be an addon that conflicts with this command (I realize I could be wrong).

Is there a way to find the conflicting addon except for turning all of them off and then load one by one?

Comment: AFAIK, no. However, it seems possible that something else could be causing this. What happens when you press Alt+B?

Comment: There‘s a blank space both outside and inside the frame (which is visible). The projecting cone is also visible when I rotate the view.

Comment: Maybe you could upload a screenshot? (It's hard to tell what this might be with only a description)

Comment: I‘m sorry, I can‘t do that, this is my first post. When I draw a clipping border around a part of my model, both the inside and the outside of my model disappears. All that remains is the border itself and the projecting cone. When doing this with factory settings, everything works OK.

Comment: Strange.. For the image you could just upload it to [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/) or something and someone will add it to your post.

Comment: I did what you proposed, and uploaded a file to Graphicall: BlenderClippingBorder.jpg

Comment: The two topmost are before and after a clipping border action with Factory Settings, the two lowermost are before and after a clipping border action with my usual setup.

Comment: I‘m sorry I brought up this clipping border thing, it was just the x that put me on the idea to check the active addons I use ; the original question remains though.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I meant post the image on pasteall and put the link to it here.. :P (without the link no one knows where the file actually is, even with the file name, because pasteall generates a number to use in place of the original name.)

Answer (score 10):

Go to *File > User Preferences > Input*, set the dropdown menu next to the search field to *Key-Binding* and enter <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>. It should list all operators bound to a key. It includes addon keybindings.

[image: User Prefernces > Input, Search by Key-Binding]

Addons can also capture events in modal operators, but it's really rare that they consume certain events and pass on the rest. So it would be pretty obvious that there's something running in the background, because a lot of actions wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much CoDEmanX for your answer. This is a great feature I was not aware of! It will be very useful also for binding and rebinding other keys, and to look out for conflicts. (It did not solve my Alt B-problem though). 
BTW, Someone hijacked my question about how to identify conflicting addons and changed it to a question about conflicting key bindings. While the latter undoubtedly is very useful to know, it‘s not at all the same thing.

Comment: @user1374 You can [rollback](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) any undesired edits. (Click the *edited xxx ago* link below your post, scroll to the desired revision, and click *rollback*)

Comment: To find keymap conflicts, you can also use the *Test Key Configuration for Conflicts* operator (accessible with the Space menu), which outputs any conflicts to the *Console*.

Comment: I knew this must exist but couldn't for the life of me find it. Works in 2.81 as well, thanks for sharing!