# Can I assign "U" for "undo"?

Tags: 3d-view, customization, shortcut

I come from a very different CAD background with years of muscle memory with other tools that I would like to use with Blender.
Right now, I would like to associate the key <kbd>U</kbd> with "undo."  However, if I assign it in User Preferences, and re-assign "Make Single User" (in "NLA Editor" group) to a different combination, I still get the "Make Single User" menu when pressing <kbd>U</kbd>.

Is there a way to re-map "undo" to <kbd>U</kbd>?  I've successfully mapped <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to zoom-out and zoom-in, respectively, for what it's worth.  (note: the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to zoom-in, which I've grown accustomed to, is the particular qualifier why I'd like another key to "undo".)

I'm currently using Blender 2.75a under Arch Linux.

Comment: [If you search for keybindings using `U`, you'll find that the conflicting operator is called `call_menu`](http://pasteall.org/pic/92986) (with `make_single_user` passed as an argument). If you disable that, then it should work as expected. I don't have time to write up a proper answer atm, but I'll write one up as soon as I can if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the shortcut you re-assigned only applies to the *[Non-Linear Animation Editor](http://blender.org/manual/animation/editors/nla.html)*.

To [find all conflicting shortcuts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3132/599), search based on key binding instead:

[image]

There are <kbd>U</kbd> shortcuts in the 3D view (both in [object mode](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/introduction.html) and [edit mode](http://blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/introduction.html)) which call the `call_menu()` operator. This is different from the NLA editor, which just runs `nla.make_single_user()` directly when called since it has no options.

Disable or re-assign the conflicting shortcuts, then it works as expected.